# Is there any harm in using a typical GET action for a PUT? (RESTfully speaking)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action that doesn't require a form. So it really only needs the one 'edit' method instead of the RESTful 'edit' --> 'update'. Is there any reason not to do this or a better way?

```
def edit
  #Do a POST(PUT)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harm is that a user could easily navigate to that url and perform a potentially destructive action.

```
/noform/edit   #URL typed by user => Action Performed
/noform/update #URL typed by user => Error is thrown, No Action Performed
```

A normal browsing experience generates `GET` requests to the server. The assumption is, any page you can easily navigate to (or type into your address bar) will not perform any data changing functions.

A `POST` request, generated via a form submission or a AJAX request expects the result that data is changed on the server.

Similarly the two rails "faked" versions of `PUT` and `DELETE` also are not actions you could simply navigate to using a browser.

**The solution**

The solution is to have only the `update` action and where you originally would have linked to `edit` use something like the following:

```
button_to "Add new tracker", noform_path, :method => :put
```

If there is any type of error, you may still need an edit path to show the user so they can correct something. But from what you have described, a single `update` action should do the trick.

Comment: So whats the solution? Should I provide a form that is basically just an empty form or a button_to?
I don't really want the user to see another screen and click another button.

Comment: The GET for a POST problem is aggravated by search engine spiders, which will perform GETs on every page of your website, systematically performing unwanted edits and deletes.

Comment: @Robert Harvey As @Dave Sims pointed out, GET is not supposed to have side effects by spec, I'd blame the bad websites, not the spiders.

Comment: @eed3si9n: Of course. It's an argument for building your website properly.

Answer (score 2):

Gets should always be [idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) -- that is they should not perform any action that will alter the state of the application, database, etc.

Just as an aside -- in true RESTful form an edit would be performed by an HTTP Update action, but Rails simulates this with a post and a hidden value on the form, since browsers don't have HTTP Updates.

It's still not clear to me why you need an update without an input field. Perhaps a little more detail would be helpful.

Comment: +1 I can never remember the word idempotent when I am talking with someone about it.

Comment: @eed3si9n -- Likely a Freudian block cause it sounds like something you'd use Viagra for.